# Banner with moving text, issue auto adjusting div size based on width and preserving body width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make banner with moving text. I came up with a way to do it but unfortunately there are two major issues with my implementation.

1. I have to manually adjust the width values in px myself depending on the length of the text.
2. It causes the body size to be larger in terms of width. I want the body to remain 100% / the same size as the window.

Any idea how I can resolve these two issues or if there is a better way to implement this?

```js
let txtAnnounce = document.createElement('div');
txtAnnounce.style = 'display: block; position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 45px; top: 65px; left: 0px; color: white; line-height: 45px; text-align: center;';
txtAnnounce.innerHTML = "Some text blah blah blach... Good for announcements with long text....! :) "
document.body.appendChild(txtAnnounce);

let txtAnnounce2 = document.createElement('div');
txtAnnounce2.style = 'display: block; position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 45px; top: 65px; left: 600px; color: white; line-height: 45px; text-align: center;';
txtAnnounce2.innerHTML = "Some text blah blah blach... Good for announcements with long text....! :) "
document.body.appendChild(txtAnnounce2);

let curLeft = 0;
let curLeft2 = 0;
setInterval(function() {
 curLeft--;
 curLeft2--;
 if (curLeft < -600) {
  curLeft = 0;
 }
 if (curLeft2 < 0) {
  curLeft2 = 600;
 }
 txtAnnounce.style.left = curLeft.toString() + 'px';
 txtAnnounce2.style.left = curLeft2.toString() + 'px';
}, 10);
```

```html
<div id="announce" style="position: absolute; display: block; top: 65px; left: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; height: 45px; width: 100%; background-color: #008aff; color: white; text-align: center; line-height: 45px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"></div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this #announce div, if you’re not doing anything with that? You’re appending your new elements to body here - if you appended them to that element instead and set overflow:hidden for it, your body width issue should be solved already.

Comment: nice thanks :) I'm an iOS dev learning HTML, everything is still a bit janky for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even give CSS animation a try and define your container sizes with respect to device's view port.

`overflow: hidden` keeps the announcement--text contained within the announcement container.

```css
.announcement {
  background:  #008aff;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.announcement--text {
  position: relative;
  left: 100vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: move 10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {left: 100vw;}
  to {left: -100vw;} //maximum length of your announcement
}
```

```html
<div class="announcement">
  <div class="announcement--text">Some text blah blah blach... Good for announcements with long text....! </div>
</div>
```